Access violation in stack frame 5 at address 0x200005fe8 of size 8
Im facing an error on devnet wich i wasnt facing on localnet.
Found that my error was duo to not having:
--deactivate-feature EenyoWx9UMXYKpR8mW5Jmfmy2fRjzUtM7NduYMY8bx33

wich "confirmed?" that it was stack error.
So, since i have everything boxed already, i decided to use remaining accounts but still getting the same error:
Anchor code:
https://gist.github.com/belivenn/d2000ea9a2b2b7e2e6de59399d447f7b
(commented accs, are the remmaining accs)
test code: https://gist.github.com/belivenn/b88b83e3631ee8ae1a057e0058a5c174
Thoughts?
Thank you in advance

Fixed by removing
.with_remaining_accounts(ctx.remaining_accounts.to_vec());
But still don't understand why does it work with the feature and without.
